# How do I create an array of pointers of type char C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I'm not very familiar with pointers, but I have an assignment that requires me to create an array of pointers of type char. I just can't seem to get the code running.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int n = 0;
    char *seasons[] = { "Winter", 
                        "Spring",  
                        "Summer",
                        "Fall"};


    cout << seasons[n] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I copied and pasted this code from the textbook, but I keep getting errors for the strings that are in the array. 
The error is  E0144: a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"

Comment: C++ 03 allowed assigning a character array literal to a `char *` but was deprecated and is now not allowed. Your C++ book (and course) is very out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if your textbook-maker did a quick-and-dirty conversion of existing C code to C++.  In C, string literals are arrays of type `char` (even though they are immutable), but in C++ they are arrays of type `const char`.

The solution here is to change the type of `seasons` to be `const char *[]` to make an array of pointers to these `const char` arrays:

```
const char *seasons[] = { "Winter", 
                          "Spring",  
                          "Summer",
                          "Fall"};
```

As an aside, I am also not a fan of your book doing `using namespace std;`.  It pollutes the global namespace with the entirety of the std namespace which can (and in my experience has) lead to conflicts that will break code.

Comment: If I didn't misremember it, the type of string literal is `const char []`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals

Comment: @JohnDing According to section 5.13.5 p8, you are correct.  I will update.